# Magento admin customer add/edit showing blank page

Tags: magento

In my magento website, when I try to edit user from backend will show blank page, 
I have not found any error on customer page. I have 600+ customer.
can you help on this please?

Comment: any news about it? one of the problems could be some module to override  `<adminhtml_customer_edit>`...but I've tried to comment out everything and the problem persists...

Answer (score 1):

In `index.php` file, Use this code to check what is the error.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Only then will able to help you.

Comment: It should give some error...cross check your syntax for this

Comment: I have added this code on page, but site is working normally,

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it is related to memory as well, try increasing memory using below code in index.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```